# JQuery Click Handlers not Working After Ajax Page Load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP MVC application where I have a partial view which is loaded via ajax each time a new comment is added.

However the jquery click handlers no longer work after an ajax page load.

```
<div id="comments">
    // Jquery links don't work after ajax page load?
    <ul>
       <li>
           <div></div>
           <a href="#" class="js-delete-comment" data-comment-id="@Model.comment.Id">
                 <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete
           </a>
       </li>
</div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Comments", null, new AjaxOptions
 {
      HttpMethod = "POST",
      LoadingElementId = "create-post-wait",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      UpdateTargetId = "comments",
      OnComplete = "AjaxCreatePostComplete()"
 }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {

     @* form details *@

 }
```

My Jquery

```
 $(function () {

        DeleteComment();

 }


 var DeleteComment = function () {

    if ($(".js-delete-comment").length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    $(".js-delete-comment").click(function (e) {
         var a = $(this); // "this" is the <a>

         window.swal({
            title: "Confirm",
            text: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true
         },
         function () {
            $.ajax({
                // do stuff
           })
         });
      });
 };


 var AjaxCreatePostComplete = function () {
        var createButton = $("#create-post-btn");
        if (createButton.length > 0) {
           createButton.attr("disabled", false);
         }

 };
```

Comment: show how you define your handlers

Comment: What `click` handler?

Comment: If click handlers are not working after new html is inserted to the DOM, then probably you should use $(parent).on() syntax to bind your click events. You havnt shown any code on that side though.

Comment: @Stephen I've added my JQuery code

Comment: You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - `$(document).on('click', '.js-delete-comment'', function() { ...` - but replace `document` with the closest ancestor which exists when the page is first rendered.

Comment: @Stephen why replace $(document) with closest ancestor. Using $(document) works?

Comment: Its more efficient :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).The difference between `on()` and `click()` is that `on()` works for **dynamically added elements**. Please try changing your click event like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.js-delete-comment',function() {
   //Add the logic for the click event here
});
```

Comment: Gave you +1 but you should explain why ;)